# Select objects with name sequence

Tags: python, select

I'm trying to organize a big scene file where some objects has this name (small sample) "US40.004, US40.005, US41.001, US51.006" or even possible for the names to be like this "US-009.009, US-009.010, US-015, US-016" as you can see the names are incremental or in sequence, and then I have some other objects with the name "USA, USDOT"

On my script I ask to select all the objects with "US" in their names but it select also the "USA, USDOT" which I don't want then to be selected.

Is there a way to tell the script to focus on selecting the objects that has US plus the sequence?

I hope this makes sense.

Here is my code so far:

```
import bpy


params = ["US", "US-"]

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if any(x in obj.name for x in params):
        obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    else: 
        obj.select_set(False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, unfortunately you did not exactly specify, which ones should be included and which ones not.

it basically uses regular expressions and searches for starting characters "US" and then an optional "-" and a number. Then a match is found. Since you know python i think you are able to adapt that to your code. Have fun!

So i made it like this:

```
import re
    
txt = {"US40.004", "US40.005", "US41.001", "US51.006", "US-009.009", "US-009.010", "US-015", "US-016", "USA", "us30.0055", "uS30.99"}
    
for eachText in txt:
    x = re.findall("US[-]?\d", eachText.upper())
        
    if (x):
        print("Yes, there is at least one match!", eachText)
    else:
        print("No match", eachText)
```

result:

```
Yes, there is at least one match! US-009.010
Yes, there is at least one match! us30.0055
Yes, there is at least one match! US51.006
Yes, there is at least one match! US-016
Yes, there is at least one match! uS30.99
Yes, there is at least one match! US-009.009
Yes, there is at least one match! US41.001
Yes, there is at least one match! US40.004
Yes, there is at least one match! US-015
Yes, there is at least one match! US40.005
No match USA
```

my change was just this: eachText.upper() -> so i convert the text to uppercase before i check whether it fits or not.

Comment: That's great thanks, the only thing I can't make my head around is what if I don't want to feed the txt list manually, for example I only add in the txt = {"US", "US-"} and the code search among all the objects the ones that has US(number sequence) and ignore the "USA" object.

Comment: i don't understand your question. the txt -> is your bpy.context.scene.objects. You just have to exchange your "if any(x in obj.name for x in params):" to "x = re.findall("US[-]?\d", obj.name)
    
    if (x):"

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and support. I think in my head the question sounded ok but was difficult to express it with words.

Comment: No problem - you are welcome

Comment: The only draw back of this solution is that the cases are not ignored. Do you know if there is a way to bypass this?

Comment: i updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

**`bpy.ops.object.select_pattern`**

As mentioned in your previous question re the operator script  [Script is selecting all the objects (unwanted)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218718/script-is-selecting-all-the-objects-unwanted) there is already a pattern matching operator, `bpy.ops.object.select_pattern` which uses [Unix file token matching](https://www.tecmint.com/use-wildcards-to-match-filenames-in-linux/).  See no need to "reinvent the wheel" and write another, which so far has no extra functionality.  Here is quick run down on how it works. *(The code of the operator is available in `bl_operators/object.py`.)*

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(
select_pattern()
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="*", case_sensitive=False, extend=True)
Select objects matching a naming pattern
```

options to extend the selection, and a case insensitive match.

```
>>> import fnmatch
>>> fnmatch.fnmatch(
fnmatch(name, pat)
Test whether FILENAME matches PATTERN.
Patterns are Unix shell style:
*       matches everything
?       matches any single character
[seq]   matches any character in seq
[!seq]  matches any char not in seq
An initial period in FILENAME is not special.
Both FILENAME and PATTERN are first case-normalized
if the operating system requires it.
If you don't want this, use fnmatchcase(FILENAME, PATTERN).
```

So for example sake will pinch

```
>>> txt = {"US40.004", "US40.005", "US41.001", "US51.006", "US-009.009", "US-009.010", "US-015", "US-016", "USA", "USADOT"}
```

make a pattern, Case sensitive, any name starting with "US" but not having  an uppercase character as third character. then end with anything

```
>>> pattern = "US[!A-Z]*"
>>> for t in txt:
...     t, fnmatch.fnmatchcase(t, pattern)
...     
('US-009.009', True)
('US40.005', True)
('US41.001', True)
('US51.006', True)
('US-016', True)
('US-009.010', True)
('USA', False)
('USADOT', False)
('US-015', True)
('US40.004', True)
```

Looks about right, so a call with instead object names matching the sample list

```
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="US[!A-Z]*", case_sensitive=True)
```

in object mode will select all objects denoted True above

To clarify, re the commentary below, it is not necessary to use the operator could (*thought this was implied TBH*) instead

```
for ob in scene.objects:
    ob.select_set(fnmatch.fnmatchcase(ob.name, pattern)) # match case
```

Re setting the active object. If the context object is no longer selected, or `None` and you wish it to be one of the selected

```
if context.selected_objects and context.object not in context.selected_objects:
    context.view_layer.objects.active = context.selected_objects[0]
```

*ie* If the active object is set and selected probably don't want to randomly change it to another of the selected objects.  (BTW most selection operators do not set the active object)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, although your answer worked properly I like to avoid the use of operators (not sure if it's a urban legend that they are slower), but it is really great having both solutions in one place.

Comment: Do you mind measuring the execution time of both scripts? I guess the operator is faster in this case. If so, there is no reason to "avoid the use of operators" IMHO @JuanCarlos

Comment: I will try to test both later, if I have understood right the whole operator thingy is that the scene gets updated everytime that an operator is called, for small scenes nothing to worry about, but when the scenes are huge and complex scripts then the speed will be noticeable.
Here is an interesting discussion about it: 
[link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators)

Comment: Depends on the case... and in this case it's just 1 call which does 2 things at once @JuanCarlos so what we can do is measuring the execution time to make sure...

Comment: yep, isn't slower and doesn't make much sense to reinvent the wheel in this case. I think it's funny that beginners in particular come up with that post... [had the same discussion 2 years ago](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/132359/31447), believers.

Comment: @JuanCarlos Did you have the time to test? Too much work for you? Would help all of us... so if you need help, just send me a file to test...

Comment: @brockmann Sadly I haven't have time, I'm full with work, andthe files I work are under NDA, but would be nice to build up a "benchmark" script where one uses 100% operators and then another script that does exactly the same but without operators.
I could run them on my files which contains crazy amount of objects and deep hierarchies.